# Array of Objects Initialization (C++)

Tags: c++, object, new-operator, dynamic-arrays

Hey guys i am i am new to C++ and through to a project i have in the university i am having some difficult times . More spesificaly :
i ve created a code for Lists and Queues (Lists name = Chain , Queues name = Queue , Product is a struct that has basicly Chains fields) [btw i ve used Sahnis book (data structures) if anyone knows it. I am stuck here :

```
int k=4;
Queue<Chain<Product>*>* x = new Queue<Chain<Product>*> [k];
for(int i=1;i<k;i++)
{
   x[i] = new Queue<Chain<Product>*> [i+1];
}
```

on the loop it throws me error : Invalid conversion from Queue*>* to int

Any idea?

Comment: Using a vector (or even a normal array) instead of pointer array will help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)   // first index is 0
{
   x[i] = Queue<Chain<Product>*>();
}
```

because

```
Queue<Chain<Product>*>* x = new Queue<Chain<Product>*> [k];
```

creates an array of `Queue<Chain<Product>*>` objects, not pointers.

Or if you want a 2-d array, you use:

```
Queue<Chain<Product>*>** x = new Queue<Chain<Product>*> * [k];
for(int 0=1;i<k;i++)
{
   x[i] = new Queue<Chain<Product>*> [i+1];
}
```

**To simplify**, you're basically attempting the following:

```
int* x = new int[4];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
   x[i] = new int[i];
```

which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Btw, I don't remember if it's doable in C++ (I work in C# and Java mainly) but can't Queue<Chain<Product>*> have a static function `.operator[int x]`? It's obviously not the case here, but just asking.

Comment: @Shingetsu yes, it's possible to overload operators, but I don't see the point of having a `static` `operator[]`.

Comment: I mean is it possible to overload an operator to be static? And if it could exist it might be used to retrieve an decoded version of the class from a certain file location or similar, those are details.

Comment: @Shingetsu I don't think it's possible, and again, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Now the code compiles , but when i run it windows pop a message that says : filename.exe stoped executing . Note that the same thing was happening without the for loop!

Comment: @Tryme_34 sounds like a different issue. Please ask a new question (**do not modify this one**) with the new code and description of what exactly happens.

Comment: i am tryin to create new question but it pops a message that says : Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. //[sorry i am new]

Answer (score 1):

In the line `x[i] = new Queue<Chain<Product>*> [i+1]` he [i+1] is wrong.
Why? Well you're creating a new object `new` keyword. and `.operator[int x]` is used in arrays. In that line you are saying it should be a new Array of size i+1 of type `Queue<Chain<Product>*>` which is faulty. Instead use `x[i] = Queue<Chain<Product>*>();`

So end code is:

```
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)//because indexes begin at 0, not 1.
{
  x[i] = Queue<Chain<Product>*>()
}
```

Note* to see a simplified version of your mistake, see other guy's post (I won't copy code around - wastes space).

Comment: Thank you for your help . when i run it it compliles perfect , however windows pop up an error when i run it that says that filename.exe stoped exececuting. Without the for loop it pops the same thing wich means that i still havent saved space for my array. Simply with my old code id didnt compile cause i had several mistakes but if i hadnt the for loop , the result is the same one with your code

Comment: @Tryme_34 it's not linked with this. Stopped executing doesnt always mean run out of memory, my guess is it's an error later in the code. Post a new question with full source.

Comment: yeah i will post tomorrow , but keep in mind that my code compiles and run okay without the initialization and when i add this code windows pop up the message
I will create a full topic tomorrow thanks for the help!